# How can I use vtt files in a HTML5 player on a SharePoint 2013 wiki page?

Tags: video, html5, accessibility

Using a html5 player (just the `<video>` tag).  Also using webvtt formatted files for captions and metadata.  If I run it in a HTML page from a web server, works fine.  If I take the same code and place it in a script editor web part, the video plays but the captions the metadata do not function. Ideas?

```
     <video id="video1" width="640" height="360" controls autoplay>
       <source src="../videofiles/20160719ITKIntroVideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
       <track  src="../siteassets/itkintro.vtt" label="English" kind="captions" id="track1" srclang="en" default>
     </video>
```

I initially wondered if I needed to get the .vtt mime type added to SharePoint, but then I noticed that it wasn't on the web server mime type list either so... hmmph.

Comment: What are you trying?  Can we see the code?

Comment: Added code in question

Comment: Have you tried adding this to a SharePoint page using SP Designer?

Comment: Have you tried a content editor web part instead of a script editor?